# Issue integrating Jest into React application

Tags: testing, reactjs, jestjs

I recently created a react application and would like to test it. I am trying to use Jest as Facebook recommends but have run into an issue. The specific error is as follows:

```
FAIL  __tests__/popup-test.js
● Runtime Error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
   at Function (native)
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

The code for popup-test.js

```
'use strict';
jest.unmock('../dist/test/popup.js');
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');
let Popup = require('../dist/test/popup.js');

describe('Popup', () => {
    it('works', () => {
        var popupTest = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <Popup />
        );
        var popupNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(popupTest);
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

As you can see, the error does not provide me with any information. I know the problem is with requiring my popup file and I can post the contents of the code here. I was hoping though that someone had encountered this problem before and could guide me in the right direction to solving it.

Best, 
Aneury Casado